# Error in Abiword on Linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've installed Abiword on my server but whenever I try to convert a document I get the following error:

```
** (abiword:13263): WARNING **: Unable to open an iconv handle from codepage 0 -> UTF-8

** (abiword:13263): WARNING **: Unable to open an iconv handle from codepage 0 -> UTF-8
Aborted
```

If anyone knows how I might be able to resolve this I'd be very grateful.

Technical details:
Abiword - Version 2.8.2
Ubuntu - Version 10.04.3

Comment: Try doing this in 2.8.6 (stable) or 2.8.9 (testing). It's possible they've fixed this bug.